# AceQL return exception with the following reason: "No parameter value for IN parameter index 4" when the value is ""

Tags: c#, sql, mssql-jdbc

The relevant code (parameter index 4):

```
...
string description = "";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", description);
...
```

What is the solution for this case? when i want to insert empty string?

Comment: Can you paste your SQL as well?

Comment: Unfortunately no, because it's a classified information. But this is a standard INSERT query without anything special that works well via SSMS.

Comment: You can always show the approach by randomly editing your code otherwise it's hard for anyone to imagine and give solution.

Comment: I updated my question. I found that it's occurre when i try to add parameters with empty value like "". What is the solution for this case?

Comment: [Don't use `AddWithValue`](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Be explicit about your types and lengths so there's no guess about what type the provider is inferring. Use `DBNull.Value` to pass explicit `NULL`s.

Comment: @Jerson, But i want empty string like "" and not NULL value.

Answer (score 0):

It's a defect of [AceQL](https://www.aceql.com/).

[image]

Thanks all !